# How to access directories above `home` in RStudio?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

Using RStudio `2022.12.0+349`, running `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`, I am bound to the `home` directory and can't navigate anywhere else in the included `Files` browser. In RStudio GUI, I can't select root with `/` like it's possible on RStudio server at work. However, in any folder I can `open with...` any `*.R` script or `*.Rproj`. I tried to find some options to set permissions in the Global Options to no avail (the `~` is greyed out and unchangable).

[image]

Interestingly in `VSCode` I can access anything I want.

Does RStudio need special permissions, or what does it need to be able to access directories above `home`?

Comment: Are you able to get above `home` directory with the `...` (Go to directory) in the upper right corner of the `Files` browser? On Windows RStudio also sort of behaves as if there is nothing above `Home` but the three dots let me set any directory in the browser.

Comment: @RobertHacken Unfortunately I just see the home `~`  and it's also greyed out, i. e. unchangeable.

Comment: use setwd() to defune the working directory